# How to check bus.get_object returned object is valid for dbus in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, dbus

I have a python script which is enabling bluetooth discovery & pairing. It using dbus to configure the bluetooth parameter. init code:

```
self.bus = dbus.SystemBus()
self.bluez_obj = self.bus.get_object('org.bluez', '/org/bluez/hci0')
self.bluetooth_props = dbus.Interface(self.bluez_obj,  "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")
```

I have seen that when I want to set the Bluetooth property by

```
self.bluetooth_props.Set(self.adapter_iface_name, "Discoverable", dbus.Boolean(value))
```

The method does not return from call.
I am doubting that bus.get_object() call of dbus for this application didn't returned valid object.

How can we check the get_object returned valid dbus object?

[Edit]
The issue started appearing recently, till now it was just working fine. this application started from the init.d during boot, and the discovery & pair is enabled based on input events. get_object & Interface is done in the application *init* only. after boot, when the input event received the utility is supposed to set timeout for Discovery & pair.

```
self.bluetooth_props.Set(self.adapter_iface_name, "DiscoverableTimeout", dbus.UInt32(value))
self.bluetooth_props.Set(self.adapter_iface_name, "PairableTimeout", dbus.UInt32(value))
```

This function does not return from the call which is directing me to doubt on the object created by get_object.
Counter side, If I add delay of 1-3 Seconds before creating the object by get_object than its just work fine. So I guess when I am calling get_object without delay, there is no valid object returned might be because of the remote end(bluez stack i guess) is not ready.
Adding delay resolves the issue but it may appear again as its just work around. I have checked change history, there is no change in init sequence or this application which is creating such issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ***didn't returned valid object***: Usually throws an error. Verify with `props = bluetooth_props.getProperties()`

Comment: You're very close to providing an actual test case that shows the issue... Doing that might help someone spot the issue you're having.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen Added further information in the Question.

Comment: @stovfl What will getProperties do?

Comment: ***What will getProperties do?***: Validate the dbus object. ***Adding delay resolves the issue***: At which stage do you running your script? Systemd?

Comment: @stovfl It is run by init.d, start-stop as default run-levels.

Comment: @stovfl self.props = self.bluetooth_props.getProperties() gives below error, "dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "getProperties" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist"

Comment: Probably wrong `"...DBus.Properties"`, can't verify myself yet, try like this [Interfaces and methods](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/tutorial.html#interfaces-and-methods). ***by init.d***: Ok, which `# Required-Start:` parameter?

Comment: @stovfl I got it, It was due to one previous change. which caused this appl to look for dbus connection even before it was created by its service. I managed to add check the instance by calling another method 'Get' a prop value and that method gives exception when the dbus object was not created, and based on that exception I retried to attempt connection. Thanks.

Comment: Consider to write a own answer showing your solution in a [mcve], thanks.